# Can't get SSH daemon running on macOS

Tags: ssh, osx, openssh, sshd

The server is running macOS Mojave 10.14.4. I'm unable to get the SSH daemon to start. After logging in locally, I run:

```
$ launchctl list | grep ssh
-   0   com.openssh.ssh-agent
$ ps -A | grep ssh 
1483 ??         0:00.00 ssh-agent -s
8483 ??         0:00.00 ssh-agent
```

The service is not active. To resolve this, I've tried:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

```
$ sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd 
$ sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`                                                                                  
Agent pid 9055
```

I'm not having any luck. The last thing I attempted before having to take a break from trying to solve this issue was:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -d     
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.9, LibreSSL 2.7.3
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

I then ran `$ ssh-keygen -A` but still receive the same message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For enabling the SSH service/daemon in MacOS do:

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

For disabling the SSH service do:

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin off
```

For checking whether it is on or off:

```
 sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
```

(Tested with Mojave)

Btw, `sshd` has to be run as root, not as you are running it. It has to be:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d &
```

Comment: I have tried `setremotelogin off` then `setremotelogin on` but it's not effective

Comment: @cryptic Mojave here and working, what do you have? Was it too fast? How you tested? Using sudo? It has got to be as root.

Comment: I'm on Mojave as well. You're right, I didn't run `sshd` as root which is not right. SSH is working now but I think the problem was that a different version of OpenSSH was also installed via Homebrew and was conflicting with the system version in some way